# Suggested Edits still in toolbar when limit is reached

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, top-bar

Suggested Edits is different from other review items in that it displays in the SE toolbar with a highlighted number (at least it does on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com)). However, when you have reached your daily maximum Suggested Edit reviews ([20 on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits), [40 on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits)), this toolbar indicator still appears:

[image]

I doubt whether this could be considered a formal [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) since it is possibly a site-wide definition and not user-specific. Since the SE Inbox is user-specific, I'm hoping it would be possible to make the Suggested Edits toolbar indicator user-specific as well. That is, only show it when there are Suggested Edits and you have enough reviews left for the day.