# Hide suggested edits indicator if done for the day

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, top-bar

When I have completed all 20 Suggested Edits for the day, I still see the indicator in the top bar for new suggested edits. Perhaps this indicator should not appear once I'm "done for the day".

Here it is:

[image: oooo something needs doing]

When I click it (it's orange so I do click it), I'm told no:

[image: oh, it doesn't]

*I don't* think *this is to do with the [20minute thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139624/review-beta-shows-no-suggested-edits-even-though-there-are-some), since I had completed the reviews an hour earlier, and I'm unsure if [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes) is talking about the same thing or not.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't show pending suggested edits to me after I run out of votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes) and [Suggested Edits still in toolbar when limit is reached](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179356/suggested-edits-still-in-toolbar-when-limit-is-reached)