# why SO shows me posts to review if I am not allowed to review them?

Tags: feature-request

I see

[image]

and then I click and see

[image]

what's the point of showing me how many articles are available to review if I can't review them? Wouldn't be better if it was shown only when some action could be performed?

Comment: [Lools like they are trying to fool you!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/april-fools).

Comment: lol april's fool maybe! ;-)

Comment: @hims056: No, that's not an April Fool.

Comment: However possible duplicate of [Don't show pending suggested edits to me after I run out of votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137074/187824) also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179356/187824